# An easy way to find a partial matching dictionary within another dictionary

Tags: python

I am running a MUD that uses python and I am trying to find an easy way to compare and match two dictionaries.  One is a partial dictionary with the required components and the other is a large mixed dictionary containing all the items upon an imaginary table or anvil.  I want to see if the required partial dictionary has a larger dictionary contained on the anvil, if so define it as item_1.

Here is what I am trying to find

```py
'req_item_1':{'pread': 'longsword', 'noun': 'blade', 'complete': 1, 'progress' 0}
```

I want to see if a single dictionary with those items can be found in this

```py
'oncon':[{'hilt_type': 'longsword', 'weight': 4, 'shopdesc': 'A hefty copper bar', 'complete': 1, 'purchased_by': 20124429, 'pread': 'exquisite copper longsword', 'quality': 6, 'id': '0600ed996c854791b9d2d0aaead3edfc', 'iname': 'copper_bar', 'creator': 'Rias', 'progress': 0, 'size': 2, 'price': 1, 'crafted_by': 20124429, 'description': 'You notice nothing unusual about the hilt.', 'tags': ['hilt'], 'registered': 0, 'material': 'copper', 'heat': 0, 'postad': '', 'janitortimer': 120, 'article': 'a', 'crafting_mark': "You notice Sam's crafting mark.", 'noun': 'hilt'}, {'iname': 'copper_bar', 'weight': 4, 'shopdesc': 'A hefty copper bar', 'complete': 1, 'purchased_by': 20124429, 'pread': 'masterfully-forged copper longsword', 'quality': 7, 'id': '355bb313b3bc4b83aa1c8f7939071f53', 'size': 2, 'tags': [], 'progress': 0, 'price': 1, 'crafted_by': 20124429, 'description': 'You notice nothing unusual about the blade.', 'blade_type': 'longsword', 'registered': 0, 'material': 'copper', 'heat': 0, 'postad': '', 'article': 'a', 'crafting_mark': "You notice Sam's crafting mark.", 'noun': 'blade', 'creator': 'Rias'}, {'summoner': 20124429, 'nutrition': 10, 'noun': 'taco', 'description': 'It looks delicious!', 'weight': 0.5, 'tags': ['food'], 'material': 'food', 'deathmsg': 'A taco suddenly disappears.', 'postad': '', 'summon_duration': 27, 'pread': '', 'article': 'a', 'bites': 5, 'id': 'd52886b9505f47488e542a6fdb46f7ea', 'size': 2}]
```

If that can be found then item_1 should be true and it will become

```py
item_1 = {'iname': 'copper_bar', 'weight': 4, 'shopdesc': 'A hefty copper bar', 'complete': 1, 'purchased_by': 20124429, 'pread': 'masterfully-forged copper longsword', 'quality': 7, 'id': '355bb313b3bc4b83aa1c8f7939071f53', 'size': 2, 'tags': [], 'progress': 0, 'price': 1, 'crafted_by': 20124429, 'description': 'You notice nothing unusual about the blade.', 'blade_type': 'longsword', 'registered': 0, 'material': 'copper', 'heat': 0, 'postad': '', 'article': 'a', 'crafting_mark': "You notice Sam's crafting mark.", 'noun': 'blade', 'creator': 'Rias'}
```

Otherwise item_1 will be false.

Comment: It appears that you're after *partial* matches, i.e. 'copper_bar' matches because 'pread' *contains* 'longsword', it's not equal to 'longsword', correct? Is that true for all / more of the requirements?

Comment: Smaller data samples could make this more readable. Also, "dictionary contained in dictionary": do you mean the same *keys* or same *key/value pairs*? And also, it it's entirety I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for partial matches (i.e. `'pread'` of `req_item_1` *contains* `'longsword'` rather than *equals* `'longsword'`). Also assuming you don't mind all matches, you're not looking for the most efficient way to get the first match. Also assuming that a partial match means that *all* elements of `req_item_1` need to be matched to be considered a good partial match.

This works under those assumptions:

```
req_item_1 = {'pread': 'longsword', 'noun': 'blade', 'complete': 1, 'progress': 0}
oncon = [
    {'hilt_type': 'longsword', 'weight': 4, 'shopdesc': 'A hefty copper bar', 'complete': 1, 'purchased_by': 20124429, 'pread': 'exquisite copper longsword', 'quality': 6, 'id': '0600ed996c854791b9d2d0aaead3edfc', 'iname': 'copper_bar', 'creator': 'Rias', 'progress': 0, 'size': 2, 'price': 1, 'crafted_by': 20124429, 'description': 'You notice nothing unusual about the hilt.', 'tags': ['hilt'], 'registered': 0, 'material': 'copper', 'heat': 0, 'postad': '', 'janitortimer': 120, 'article': 'a', 'crafting_mark': "You notice Sam's crafting mark.", 'noun': 'hilt'},
    {'iname': 'copper_bar', 'weight': 4, 'shopdesc': 'A hefty copper bar', 'complete': 1, 'purchased_by': 20124429, 'pread': 'masterfully-forged copper longsword', 'quality': 7, 'id': '355bb313b3bc4b83aa1c8f7939071f53', 'size': 2, 'tags': [], 'progress': 0, 'price': 1, 'crafted_by': 20124429, 'description': 'You notice nothing unusual about the blade.', 'blade_type': 'longsword', 'registered': 0, 'material': 'copper', 'heat': 0, 'postad': '', 'article': 'a', 'crafting_mark': "You notice Sam's crafting mark.", 'noun': 'blade', 'creator': 'Rias'},
    {'summoner': 20124429, 'nutrition': 10, 'noun': 'taco', 'description': 'It looks delicious!', 'weight': 0.5, 'tags': ['food'], 'material': 'food', 'deathmsg': 'A taco suddenly disappears.', 'postad': '', 'summon_duration': 27, 'pread': '', 'article': 'a', 'bites': 5, 'id': 'd52886b9505f47488e542a6fdb46f7ea', 'size': 2}
]

matches = [
    item for item in oncon for k in req_item_1.keys()
    if k in item and ((type(req_item_1[k]) is str and req_item_1[k] in item[k]) or 
                      req_item_1[k] == item[k])
]
item_1 = matches[0]

print(item_1)
```

`matches` is constructed by a list comprehension that:

- iterates over all items `item` in `oncon`
- iterates over all keys `k` in `req_item_1` for each `item`
- checks if the key `k` is in the `item` and
- if so, checks if the type of `req_item_1[k]` is a string and it is found in the `item`'s value for key `k`
- or otherwise, if the `item`'s value for key `k` is the same as `req_item_1[k]`
- if `True`, `item` is added to the list that's being constructed

`item_1` is assigned the first of all the matches in `matches`.

Comment: Thanks this works like I want it to!  Sorry about the large data sample but I wanted to show what I was sorting through to better clarify the question.  This also gives me enough to work with should I need to tweak anything.